# didReceiveRemoteNotification with UIBackgroundFetchResult is not working in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement FCM notification in IOS with `content_available: true` . This way IOS will notify my application when new notification arrives without adding that notification to in the notification tray hence i can do background fetch and then show local notification when my app is ready with the content.

I was able to implement a sample application with FCM which works as per my requirement mentioned before. when i tried to integrate working code with my application my not longer receiving data notification trigger with `content_available: true`. However Normal notification implementation without  `content_available: true` (new notification visible to the user and App is not notified of the new notification when it arrives.) is working.
The only difference i can see is that Firebase initiation code is being triggered differently as shown below.

In **working project** im initializing Firebase from **AppDelegate**

```
@interface AppDelegate () <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

NSString *const kGCMMessageIDKey = @"gcm.message_id";


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [self initFirebase];

    return YES;
}
```

In the **project that is NOT working** I'm initializing firebase from **ViewController** when user clicks on a button.

```
#import "LoginPageViewController.h"

@import UserNotifications;

@interface LoginPageViewController () <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@end

@implementation LoginPageViewController

NSString *const kGCMMessageIDKey = @"gcm.message_id";


- (void)initFirebase{
    [FIRApp configure];
    .
    .
    .
     }
```

All other methods are same between those two application and all the triggers are working perfectly, following is the method that handles FCM data notification, this gets called in working project whenever i sent FCM notification but never being called in the other project.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler{
    printf("#B received notification!");
    //NSLog(@"#B received notification");
    //handle the notification here
}
```

Has anyone successfully implemented FCM integration where it is being initialized outside AppDelegate class? 
How do i make sure didReceiveRemoteNotification is being called in that case? any pointers would be much appreciated.

Below is the complete LoginViewController.m if thats helpful  in anyway.

```
//
//  LoginPageViewController.m
//  ios
//
//  Created by user on 9/12/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 binfer. All rights reserved.
//

#import "LoginPageViewController.h"

@import UserNotifications;

@interface LoginPageViewController () <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@end

@implementation LoginPageViewController

NSString *const kGCMMessageIDKey = @"gcm.message_id";


- (void)initFirebase{
    [FIRApp configure];

    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
        printf("#B IOS 9");
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    } else {
        // iOS 10 or later
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
        printf("#B IOS 10+");
        UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
        UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
        | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
        | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        }];

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        [FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;
#endif
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    NSLog(@"#B fir token is %@",[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]);
    printf("#B FCM token received: %s", [[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token] UTF8String]);
}
- (void)initFirebase1{
    //[START configure_firebase]
    [FIRApp configure];
    // [END configure_firebase]

    // [START set_messaging_delegate]
    [FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;
    // [END set_messaging_delegate]

    // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
    // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
    // [START register_for_notifications]
    if ([UNUserNotificationCenter class] != nil) {
        // iOS 10 or later
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
        UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert |
        UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
         requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
         completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
             // ...
         }];
    } else {
        // iOS 10 notifications aren't available; fall back to iOS 8-9 notifications.
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    // [END register_for_notifications]

    NSString *token = FIRMessaging.messaging.FCMToken;
    printf("#B initFirebase done! %s,", [token UTF8String]);
}

// [START refresh_token]
- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(NSString *)fcmToken {
    printf("#B FCM token received: %s", [fcmToken UTF8String]);
    NSLog(@"FCM registration token: %@", fcmToken);
    // Notify about received token.
    NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fcmToken forKey:@"token"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:
     @"FCMToken" object:nil userInfo:dataDict];
    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    printf("#B Unable to register for remote notificaiton");
    NSLog(@"#B Unable to register for remote notifications: %@", error);
}

// This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
// If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs device token can be paired to
// the FCM registration token.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"APNs device token retrieved: %@", deviceToken);
      printf("#B APNs device token  retrieved");

    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs device token here.
    // [FIRMessaging messaging].APNSToken = deviceToken;
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

    // Print message ID.
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        printf("#B Message recieved: %s,", [kGCMMessageIDKey UTF8String]);
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
    printf("#B full Message recieved");
    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone);
}

// Handle notification messages after display notification is tapped by the user.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(void))completionHandler {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
          printf("#B Message recieved: %s,", [kGCMMessageIDKey UTF8String]);
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    completionHandler();
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler{
    printf("#B received notification!");
    //NSLog(@"#B received notification");
    //handle the notification here
}

- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
    printf("Recieved data message:");
    NSLog(@"Received data message: %@", remoteMessage.appData);
}


// [START receive_message]
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

    // Print message ID.
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

- (IBAction)registrationClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (IBAction)loginButton:(UIButton *)sender {
}
- (IBAction)keepMeSignedInSwitch:(UISwitch *)sender {
}

@end
```